# Very bad performance using WSFederationHttpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, wif, ws-federation

I have very bad performance using WSFederationHttpBinding - iis process only 250 requests per second.

Binding:

```
public class CustomFactoryActive : ServiceHostFactory
    {
        protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
            CommonConf.ConfigureServiceHost(host);


            string issuerAddress = ConfigManager.ActiveSTS;
            string issuerMexAddress = issuerAddress + "/mex";

            WSFederationHttpBinding wsFedBinding = new WSFederationHttpBinding();
            wsFedBinding.Security.Mode = WSFederationHttpSecurityMode.Message;
            wsFedBinding.ReliableSession.Enabled = false;

            wsFedBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = wsFedBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = Constants.MaxFileSize;

            XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas = wsFedBinding.ReaderQuotas;
            quotas.MaxArrayLength = quotas.MaxBytesPerRead = quotas.MaxStringContentLength =
                quotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = quotas.MaxDepth = (int)Constants.MaxFileSize;

            var messageSecurity = wsFedBinding.Security.Message;

            messageSecurity.IssuedTokenType = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV1.1";
            messageSecurity.IssuedKeyType = SecurityKeyType.SymmetricKey;
            messageSecurity.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
            messageSecurity.NegotiateServiceCredential = false;

            messageSecurity.IssuerAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(issuerAddress));
            messageSecurity.IssuerMetadataAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(issuerMexAddress));


            WS2007HttpBinding ws2007HttpBinding = new WS2007HttpBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
            var wsHttpSecurity = ws2007HttpBinding.Security;
            wsHttpSecurity.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;//авторизация по логину и паролю
            wsHttpSecurity.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = true;
            wsHttpSecurity.Message.AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default;

            messageSecurity.IssuerBinding = ws2007HttpBinding;

            ContractDescription contractDescription = ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(ISignService));

            EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(baseAddresses[0]);
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(contractDescription, wsFedBinding, endpointAddress);
            host.Description.Endpoints.Add(endpoint);

            return host;
        }
    }
```

My wcf test method does nothing - it simply returns 1 byte.

But when I use simple WSHttpBinding with message security without any WIF saml tokens I get approx. 4000 requests per second

I cant uderstand why

Answer (score 6):

You should set up and configure WCF Tracing to see an outline of where the time is spent in the WCF architecture, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx for more details.

When you enable the tracing and look at the requests, you are *likely* to see (in a test environment with single caller calling the same service multiple times) that the STS is being called only once and subsequent calls contain a cached token. However, all calls will still set up the secured connection and thus validate the token (which will take some CPU time) for every call. Alternatively you may/can verify all of this via method level profiling the service host which will show more clearly where the time is exactly being spent on.

Answer (score 3):

Emulate the security token (don't use the actual STS) and see how your performance goes. I assume that part is your bottle neck.

Comment: STS asked for token only once(proved by iis logs), so STS is not a bottleneck

Answer (score 3):

I saw a case where `NegotiateServiceCredential = true` added multiple network round trips when opening the channel. Try changing `wsHttpSecurity.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential` to `false` and specify the service cerdentials at the client.

Answer (score 3):

It could also be possible that the validation of the certificate takes a lot of time. You could try to change the behavior of your client so skip certificate validation and revokation.

```
//Client
var clientCredentialsBehavoir = behaviors.Find<FederatedClientCredentials>();
clientCredentialsBehavoir.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode =                     X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
clientCredentialsBehavoir.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;

//The same can be done on the server
var serviceConfiguration = new ServiceConfiguration();
serviceConfiguration.CertificateValidationMode =   X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
```

This should not be done in a production environment!

You can do this via the appconfig, too.

Answer (score 2):

SAML tokens are encrypted - how depends on your config. In your case, it seems that you're using `SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default`, which I think is `AES256`.

Any time decryption/encryption occurs, it will take time for the CPU to do the number crunching. The amount of time/effort that it takes depends on a wide range of factors, but I don't see it being all *that* unusual that you are seeing the difference in request handling capabilities that you are seeing.

As mentioned by other responses, even if the token is cached, the token must still be validated and decrypted, each of which involves running the contents of the token through one or more algorithms.

My recommendation: perform some profiling using the different `SecurityAlgorithmSuite` constants, and compare the results.

One place to start could be comparing `SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic128` to `.Basic256`. The `256` constant is equivalent to the default option.